# An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (MyApp.deps.json) was not found:

Tags: asp.net-core, ubuntu-18.04

My project is built in `Azure Pipelines` using `SDK 3.1.101`, without any errors/warnings, but after deployment to the host (`Ubuntu 18.04`), I'm getting error:

```
Error:
    An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (MyApp.deps.json) was not found:
        package: 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient', version: '1.0.19269.1'
        path: 'runtimes/unix/lib/netcoreapp2.1/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll'
```

Little bit of investigation pointed me that problem comes from `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` which references `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`.

Looks like it tries to find library from v2.1, somehow strange to me - but it's LST, so maybe...

Initially on the hosting had only `aspnetcore-runtime-3.1`, so, I thought that by installing v2.1 may fix the problem, and installed `aspnetcore-runtime-2.1`, then SDKs for both versions but nothing helped so far :(

Any thoughts how to fix it?

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail, perhaps some screenshots or chunks of your pipeline yaml? `dotnet publish` on your api project should create the `runtimes/unix/netcoreapp2.1/` directory (and other folders like it) for you. Then if you're publishing your AzDO artifacts correctly there shouldn't be any deficiencies.

Comment: @JoshGust, this was two years ago, I don't even have that Linux server anymore to provide some screenshots, and because v2.1 is out of support - I don't have it on my machine to try recreate. Check "Accepted Answer" it contains some details about how I've fixed it. In the end - I highly recommend you to update to at least v3.1 which is LST or even higher version (code changes are minor).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a way to fix it!

By looking into my project's `./bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/` directory, fount that, even if I build it on Windows, it still creates `runtimes/unix` directory and puts there that DLLs that were missed in `Ubuntu`.

So, by manually upload all from `runtimes/unix` to the deployment machine, into `CONTENT_ROOT` of my application - **solved it**.

P.S.
Still have no idea why it wasn't uploaded during deployment process.
But this is another story ;)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by changing

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
```

into

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.1" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after we upgraded an application to .NET Core.
The old version of the application just needed DLL files along with the EXE to be deployed. So I just did the same and this ran fine from my own machine but I got the error in the question when running the same app from a VM.

After looking at the error more closely, I tried copying the **runtimes** folder to the VM and this resolved my issue.

I'm still unclear why the app can run on my machine without the runtimes folder in situ.

Answer (score 0):

In  my case the name of the namespace defined VS 2019 GUI ->Properties->Application->AssemblyName and DefaultNameSpace was not the same as the top namespace in the application.